# Javascript - Nested function doesn't call stubbed function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a nested function which is stubbed.
I am using sinon for stubbing.

```
function logger(){

    function log(msg){

       sendMsg(msg)
    }

    var sendMsg = function (msg){
        console.log("original func")
    }

    return {
        log:log,
        sendMsg:sendMsg
    }
}
```

I am stubbing  the 'sendMsg' func  and trying to call it from `log`  function, but instead of the stubed function, the original one is called.

The weirdest thing is that when I call `sendMsg` with `this.sendMsg` it calls the stub.

Im sure there is a JS principle im not aware of, Ill be glad you can point me to one..

Thanks

Comment: There is no implicit `this` in JavaScript. Thus `sendMsg()` and `this.sendMsg()` do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `log()` function refers directly to the symbol `sendMsg` to call the function. The only `sendMsg` visible to `log()` is that local variable to which the the "real" function is assigned. Changing the value of the "sendMsg" property on that returned object cannot affect that; `log()` will **always** call the "real" `sendMsg()` function.

If `log()` were written to call `this.sendMsg` instead, then your stub function would be called.

Comment: thanks, but I would like to know what is the logic behind that

Comment: @yuria the "logic"?  That's just the way the language works. Why would that call directly to `sendMsg()` change just because some object has changed? The returned object from the outer function doesn't have any special influence over how that code works, since the code in `log()` does not make use of `this` at  all.

Comment: but if the code in `log()` does use `this` why it works differently?

Comment: @yuria because the value of `this` is determined by how the function is **called**. If you call `object.log("hello")` from the object returned by the outer function, then the value of `this` will be a reference to that object. Because you've replaced the "sendMsg" property value with the stub, the stub will be called. The **direct** reference to `sendMsg()`, by contrast, has nothing to do with that returned object.